# How to set the limit on incoming HTTPServletRequest object?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-3.0, java-6

I am looking for the options to set the max limit on incoming http request like instance want to set the limit not to exceed over 6MB? How can i achieve that?

My code snippet;

```
public String getContent(HttpServletRequest request)
                    throws IOException {

                StringBuffer lines = new StringBuffer();
                try {
//Tried the below line not sure if it is right but did not work    
//BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(request.getReader(),60048);

                   if(req.getContentLength()< 600048) {
                    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        lines.append(line);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException exc) {

                    throw exc;
                }
                return lines.toString();
            }

           }//Check for size ends here
        }
```

Comment: What kind of application/web server are you using? Also where is this `getContent` method used?

Comment: Websphere is the application server and getContent is invoked in doPost() method

Comment: Have tried editing it's configuration?

Comment: Also what version are you using?

Comment: Websphere 7 team is different and yes they do not have any settings to check on size limit over the incoming request. So probably trying to look for an option to handle it within application itself. Is this good idea to handle within the server configuration rather than at application level?

Comment: I'm going to write a simple answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible ways for you to implement such a functionality. For once, I am not very familiar with WebSphere so correct me if I'm wrong.

- **Option 1 - Handling this on the server level**

WebSphere seems to offer a configuration property very similar to Tomcat's `maxPostSize`.  For Tomcat's case this limits the max post size on the connector level. I suppose that the equivalent for this for WebSphere is `PostSizeLimit`. You can go ahead and edit the application server's configuration file set this to the desired size (in bytes).

- **Option 2 - Handling this programmatically**

`HttpServletRequest` does not offer an out of the box way of inspecting the incoming request's size. To overcome this there are two options. One is to attempt to retrieve the value of the `Content-Length` header. Problem is that this may not be present always. Another potential issue for this, is that this returns only the size of the body (not including headers) as this is defined [here](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html).

If you're sure that this header is always going to be present and assuming that you don't care about the headers' size you can go ahead and try this.

Another way would be to try to use `ServletRequest#getContentLength` which may also return the size of the body.

One last final way would be for you to obtain the `inputStream` of the request, use a `BufferedReader` to read it locally and store it in a byte array. With this in hand you should be able to determine the size. Only problem regarding this solution is that a HttpServletRequest inputStream can only be read once, meaning that you'll need to cache it somehow (a filter based solution would work really good for this).

In any, way the real thing aside from doing the above, is what you do in case the size is over the desired limit. In you code sample you seem to attempt to read it until the desired size is attained and then just return whatever you have read so far. My thinking is that this is wrong, as you may end up with an invalid request body. I think that it would be better for you to actually drop the request in case it's over the allowed limit.

I hope the above help.

Comment: Thank you for putting out such detailed answer. I just updated my code snippet, do you think it is good idea to check the size right before parsing the incoming request? Like putting a condition wrapper for checking the size limit?

Comment: Did it work out for you? Well it depends on what you want to achieve with the request. This was never specified in your original question.

Comment: I have to try this out did not try yet as the deployment process is quiet verbose. So what i was trying to ask earlier is if i use req.getContentLength with my if condition wrapper to check the size of the request if not exceeded the max then allowed to inside the condition? In short am trying to prevent DOS attack and preventing anyone to send overwhelming request by limiting it to max file size 6 MB.

Comment: i added the wrapper condition in my actual code above

Comment: Makes sense. I have seen quite a lot of people doing this. I suppose that in that case, going with the option of limiting the post size on the actual application would have been better. Documentation of WebSphere should give you some more details. If you manage to get it working based on the information I provided, please upvote and make this the accepted answer. Also please let me know if the content length check actually works (I did not try it myself).

Comment: The gist is we wanted to limit the size so that any attacker do not send the request over the actual RAM of the system or wherever the server is resided. Anyways will let you know about the outcome, though i have already upvoted  your answer as it makes lot of sense.

Comment: So basically getContentLength returns the size of the request data, when it returns -1 what does it means?